# Getting full size image using Android ContactProvider PHOTO_ID on Gingerbread

Tags: android, contacts, photo

I have obtained the image using ContactsContracts.Contacts.PHOTO_ID as follows:

```
      public Bitmap getBitmapFromId(Uri contactUri)
{
    Bitmap bitmap=null;
    String[] projection={ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID};
    Cursor c=getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
    if(!isCursorBad(c))
    {
        int photo_id=c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        Log.d(TAG, "The photo id is "+photo_id);
        Cursor c2=getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO}, ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID+"=?"+" AND "+ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE+"=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(photo_id),ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE}, null);
        if(!isCursorBad(c2))
        {
            byte[] data=c2.getBlob(0);
            Log.d(TAG, "Got byte data of length "+data.length);
            bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        }
    }   
    return bitmap;
}
```

This only returns the thumbnail of the image.How can I obtain the full size image using the PHOTO_ID column?

NOTE: I have found that:

```
    PHOTO_URI              API LEVEL 11
    PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI    API LEVEL 11
    PHOTO_FILE_ID          API LEVEL 14
    PHOTO_ID               API LEVEL 05
```

Thus,the choice of PHOTO_ID(targeting API level 10 and above).

Is there any way of getting full size image from the ContactsProvider maze?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the full size photo using the following code, though I've found this doesn't work when I tested on Android 2.3.3 (Gingerbread). I'm not completely sure on this, but I think that maybe Gingerbread only allows thumbnail size photos (not full size).

```
final Uri person = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
final Uri photo = Uri.withAppendedPath(person, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.DISPLAY_PHOTO);
```